# Calculate the age and Insert it to an already column via SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

[image]

I have a table in database which is already has the data, but now I added new column called `Vol_Age` and it has `NULL` value. I want that column filled by calculating Age, the data comes from `Vol_Date_of_Birth` column, I need a query that calculate the age and insert it to the `Vol_Age` column.
which we can use `Insert` or `Update`, and how we can do it?!

Please forgive me for my English.
Thanks

Comment: so you google'd for this and found ... nothing?

Comment: Yes, I was searching for long time ago but I did not find something useful and solved my problem

Comment: You really ought to edit your image to obscure everything but the DOB & Age columns. Those 10 people you show here probably wouldn't appreciate having their email addresses put on display like this.

Comment: @alroc.... those dont look real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that since you added the column to the database, any values within that column will retain their value.  As time goes on, you will need to keep updateding the values within the database.

Another approach would be to remove the column and make it a computed column instead.  This way, the age is caculated at query time rather than from your last update.

```
ALTER TABLE tbname ADD Vol_Age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, Vol_Date_Of_Birth, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I agree.  Putting a column in the table...whose values "changes with the wind" is not a good design.  This is why they developed the computed-column.  You have the DOB, use it wisely.  You can also create a VIEW with that column in the return result. (again, with the view, there isn't an actual "Age" column, in only appears that way.

Comment: The Column is already set, means that the table has the column already and that makes problem I cloud not set the type of that column. I solve it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DateDiff function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,GETDATE(),Vol_Age)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
UPDATE Personal_Info SET vol_Age = (SELECT (DATEDIFF(YEAR, Vol_Date_Of_Birth,GETDATE()) + CONVERT(REAL,(DATEDIFF(month, Vol_Date_Of_Birth,GETDATE()) % 12))/12) AS AGE
FROM    Personal_Info)
```

Comment: You need to add your table on the FROM Clause. I will edit my answer. Just a second.

Comment: try it again, Updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it is VolunteersAffairs..Personal_Info

Comment: Just use an update statement! `UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = 'some values'...`

Comment: Ok. Now can you mark as answer? :D To use it on update do something like this:
       UPDATE Personal_Info SET vol_Age = (SELECT (DATEDIFF(YEAR, Vol_Date_Of_Birth,GETDATE()) + CONVERT(REAL,(DATEDIFF(month, Vol_Date_Of_Birth,GETDATE()) % 12))/12) AS AGE
FROM Personal_Info)

Comment: try it now! answer doing what you want. Just test it for us

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade| Hello, where have you been?!!

Comment: What is the PK of that table??

Comment: sorry, I got the answer select statement and then I just use update on it and it works so fine.
 `UPDATE Personal_Info SET vol_Age = (select convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, Vol_Date_of_Birth, getdate())/365.25));`

Answer (score 0):

I got answers from different places and merged the answers to get this:

```
 UPDATE Personal_Info SET vol_Age = (select convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, Vol_Date_of_Birth, getdate())/365.25));
```